# Updating the value of data attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<a class="toggle" href="#toggle">
    <img src="app/css/images/tock.png" alt="No" data-id="4" data-block="1">
</a>
```

I want to update the value of the `src` and `data-block` attributes using jQuery. How do I do this?

**Update:** As I have many image elements, I want to update the value of a specific image by using `data-id`.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

```
$('.toggle img').data('block', 'something');
$('.toggle img').attr('src', 'something.jpg');
```

Use [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and [jQuery.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

I'm showing them to you separately for the sake of understanding.

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to mention, but i want to select specific img by using data-id, the selector should select the image element by data id for example something like `$('toggle img[data-id=4]')`

Comment: You are almost there: `$('toggle img[data-id="4"]')`

Comment: FWIW, I am finding that in order to override a data-attribute, you have to use `.attr` and not `.data`. This is confusing because jQuery is able to attach data to the element, but that might not be reflected in the dom if the data-attribute already existed.

Comment: To show what I mean in the above comment, see my jsfiddle. The console log of the elements data shows the updated value but if you look at the console log of the element, in its dataset, (or view it with the elements inspector) you will see the original value. WAT http://jsfiddle.net/joesepi/kycajL4e/2/

Comment: I never use .data, it always break. it do not see update at all and it never worked well for me. i always use .attr

Comment: be aware that .data('block', something) doesn't actually change the DOM

Comment: i just came across this issue, is there a reason why .data('block', something)   doesn't change the DOM. The jQuery documentation doesn't appear to explain this, whats the point in implementing this feature?

Comment: For anyone wondering about @ugotchi's question, the answer is that jQuery's `data` is used to access a "data store" that jQuery adds to DOM elements. You can use it to store any data you like on any node in your DOM. The tricky bit is that this data store gets its initial values from the `data` attribute on the DOM node. So, you can _read_ the data attributes using `data()`, but if you _write_ to `data()` you're only writing to the data store, not to the original attributes.

Answer (score 30):

```
$('.toggle img').each(function(index) { 
    if($(this).attr('data-id') == '4')
    {
        $(this).attr('data-block', 'something');
        $(this).attr('src', 'something.jpg');
    }
});
```

or

```
$('.toggle img[data-id="4"]').attr('data-block', 'something');
$('.toggle img[data-id="4"]').attr('src', 'something.jpg');
```

Comment: using jQuery.attr and not jQuery.data, as proposed in this answer, causes bugs in some browsers. have been there.

Comment: using data is indeed a good suggestion, but keep in mind that it does not modify the original dom element, which might give issues with other jquery that depends on the changing of the dom. http://www.peterbe.com/plog/data-and-attr-in-jquery

Answer (score 18):

I want to change the width and height of a div. data attributes did not change it. Instead I use:

```
var size = $("#theme_photo_size").val().split("x"); // text input like value: 640x480
$("#imageupload_img").width(size[0]);
$("#imageupload_img").attr("data-width", size[0]);
$("#imageupload_img").height(size[1]);
$("#imageupload_img").attr("data-height", size[1]);
```

be careful:

```
$("#imageupload_img").data("height", size[1]); //did not work
```

did not set it

```
$("#imageupload_img").attr("data-height", size[1]); // yes it worked!
```

this has set it.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.toggle img').data('block', 'something').attr('src', 'something.jpg');
```

Comment: this is not what i wanted, i have updated my question please have a look.