# jquery - change attribute according ID

Tags: jquery

how do I search by ID and change "data-totalReplies" value?

```
<div id="newReply" data-totalReplies="'.mysql_num_rows($replyQuery).'"></div>
```

Comment: A simple Google turns up many duplicates, did you check them? [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874320/updating-the-value-of-data-attribute-using-jquery), [example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935191/adding-data-attribute-to-dom), etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data attributes are also a generic attributes of the HTML tags. So it can easily be alter with the generic attr() as follows:

```
 $('#newreply').attr('data-totalReplies','new_values');
```